# Call react this.function inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, function, this

I have a Jquery function on my componentWillMount at reactJS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 this.myFunction();
}
```

And a arrow function declared down bellow:

```
myFunction = () => {
 alert("Jquery is ready!");
}
```

Why im getting this.myFunction() is not a function error?

Comment: Because `this` doesn’t refer to the react component. Not quite sure if jQuey sets it for `ready`. It’s either `document` or `window`.

Comment: And how can i refer myFunction?

Comment: May you post the code which accurately demonstrates the issue your facing?

Comment: If `this` outside that function references the component you can use an arrow function instead

Comment: You don't need jQuery .... run your function in `componentDidMount `

Comment: Asking for problems trying to use jQuery in React app

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn’t be a reason to use jQuery at all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `this` inside another function which it is not bound to your object and therefore changes the scope of `this`.

You can try

a) Make the Function an arrow function:

```
$(document).ready(() => this.myFunction());
```

b) Bind the outside `this` into the anonymous function

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 this.myFunction();
}.bind(this));
```

c) Create a variable holding `this`

```
var self = this;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 self.myFunction();
});
```

Comment: FWIW, it’s irrelevant that the function is anonymous. The same would happen with a named function.

Comment: You're absolutely right of course!